# JAXB: Getting the error "Cannot resolve the name xxx to a(n) 'type definition' component."

Tags: java, jaxb

I'm trying to use JAXB to unmarshal some XML but I seem to get the error "Cannot resolve the name xxx to a(n) 'type definition' component." when I hit the line containing **sf.newSchema(...)**:

```
JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance("some.package.name");

Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();

SchemaFactory sf = SchemaFactory.newInstance(javax.xml.XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);

Collection<Source> sources = new ArrayList<Source>();

sources.add(new StreamSource(new File("dog.xsd")));
sources.add(new StreamSource(new File("cat.xsd")));
sources.add(new StreamSource(new File("cow.xsd")));
sources.add(new StreamSource(new File("horse.xsd")));
sources.add(new StreamSource(new File("mouse.xsd")));

Schema schema = sf.newSchema(sources.toArray(new Source[0]));  // SAXParseException thrown here
unmarshaller.setSchema(schema);

unmarshaller.unmarshal(socket.getInputStream());
```

The exception trace looks like this:

```
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: src-resolve: Cannot resolve the name 'xxx:xxx' to a(n) 'type definition' component.
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:195)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.error(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:131)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:384)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.reportSchemaErr(XSDHandler.java:2537)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.reportSchemaError(XSDHandler.java:2528)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.getGlobalDecl(XSDHandler.java:1396)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDComplexTypeTraverser.traverseSimpleContent(XSDComplexTypeTraverser.java:373)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDComplexTypeTraverser.traverseComplexTypeDecl(XSDComplexTypeTraverser.java:249)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDComplexTypeTraverser.traverseGlobal(XSDComplexTypeTraverser.java:160)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.traverseSchemas(XSDHandler.java:1255)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.parseSchema(XSDHandler.java:579)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaLoader.loadSchema(XMLSchemaLoader.java:552)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaLoader.loadGrammar(XMLSchemaLoader.java:519)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaLoader.loadGrammar(XMLSchemaLoader.java:485)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.validation.XMLSchemaFactory.newSchema(XMLSchemaFactory.java:211)
    ...
```

I had the same issue when I used the XJC compiler to generate sources from each of the above XSDs, but managed to resolve the issue by using a catalog (xjc -catalog ...).

Does anyone know what the programmatic equivalent of a catalog is?

Comment: What's the detail message from the `SAXParseException`?  What do the XSD files look like?

Comment: Does "xxx" appear in any of the schemas?

Comment: "The programmatic equivalent of a catalog" is probably an EntityResolver.

Comment: @Ed I just replaced the real names with xxx because part of the code I am working on is private.

Comment: Can you post the schema? If you can't post the actual schema/code, show us some *actual* schema/code that reproduces the same problem.

Comment: share your xml so that it can be reviewed easily

Answer (score 1):

I got a similar issue because my XSD was importing another XSD.  The way to solve it is by getting all the imported XSDs, and including it in building the schema.

e.g.

```
InputStream imported2Schema = ...getResourceAsStream("/com/path/to/Imported2.xsd");
Source imported2Source = new StreamSource(imported2Schema);
InputStream imported1Schema = ...getResourceAsStream("/com/path/to/Imported1.xsd");
Source imported1Source = new StreamSource(imported1Schema);
InputStream metadataSchema = ...getResourceAsStream("/com/path/to/metadata.xsd");
Source metadataSource = new StreamSource(metadataSchema);
Source[] schemaSources = new Source[] {imported2Source, imported1Source, metadataSource};
Schema schema = sf.newSchema(schemaSources);
```